What happens if i mix c with c++ in a c++ script?
Let me give an example:
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    printf("Hello World");
    return 0;
}

if i do things like this in a bigger project can it have bad consequences?
I use vscode and code runner extension fyi

I will usually work until you get into dark corners. But why would you want to do something like that ? it's bad practice (BTW - you need #include <stdio.h> for printf anyway). Note that there are cases you need to use C code from C++, but these are advanced issues and probably not relevant here.

Nit-picking, but C++ is not a scripting language, so it's not "C++ script". It's code.

This has "I got called out in code review and am looking for validation" vibes. And since it got mentioned, the Code Runner extension is hot garbage for C++.

just try to stick to the "Team coding guidelines", if the code-base does something, just do the same as the rest of the code, a big project where everyone has his own style and preferences is worse than one where everyone is sticking to the same bad style, a bad guideline is better than no guideline, if everyone is using printf then i can search for printf in the codebase when the time comes to replace it with something better, but if everyone is using a different function then the job is a lot harder

Synchronization with stdio is enabled by default.

General recommendation: isolate the C stuff in a C file as much as possible. Compile it as C. Link it to the C++. You will generally have fewer surprises.

Side note: Migrate away from Code Runner as quick as you can. It doesn't scale well to even moderately complicated programs. The C/C++ for Visual Studio Code extension is a bit harder to set up, but works better longer. You can also jump straight to CMake, but CMake is its own language and you probably don't want to have to learn two languages at the same time.

You can use the macro __cplusplus to determine, at compile-time, if the current compiler you're using is a C or C++ one, for example: #ifndef __cplusplus / #error Compling with a C compiler / #endif or #ifdef __cplusplus / #error Compling with a C++ compiler / #endif C specifically forbids the macro to be defined in a conforming implemantation; C++ specifically mandates that __cplusplus be defined in a conforming implementation

@wohlstad "BTW - you need #include <stdio.h> for printf anyway" - in C++, you should use <cstdio> instead. Many C headers in <xxx.h> form have a corresponding <cxxx> form in C++.

@RemyLebeau thanks for the reminder, forgot about that. I try to avoid legacy C stuff anyway as much as I can when I use C++.


What happens if i mix c with c++ in a c++ script?

You can't.  To whatever extent it is correct to characterize the source as C++, everything in it must be interpreted as C++ code.  That's what calling it C++ means.
C++ shares a lot of syntax with C, and you can call (suitably declared) C standard library functions from C++. Using idiomatic C syntax that is also valid C++, or calling C standard library functions, does not make your C++ source an admixture of C and C++.  It can, however, make it non-idiomatic C++.

if i do things like this in a bigger project can it have bad consequences?

Possibly.  For example, if in one source you use C stdio functions to interact with the program's standard input and output, whereas in another source you interact with standard input and output via C++ iostreams, you might get undesired interactions.
Also, there is code that is valid in C but not in C++, as well as code that is valid in both but means different things in C than in C++.  If you do not maintain discipline regarding which language you are writing in then you are more likely to make mistakes at those boundaries, which can be difficult to detect.
Of course, this all assumes that the project does not have formalized coding conventions speaking to the subject.  If it does, then the question is moot: you adhere to the conventions because they are the law of the project.  It doesn't matter in that case whether you like the conventions or think they should allow more leeway.

Classic example of a C feature not available in C++: Variable length arrays. This can come as a huge shock to people raised on GCC and GCC-compatible compilers.

@user4581301 compound literals. designated initializers. implicit pointer conversion. Some edge cases with casts and operator precedence

It is simple: Everything that you present to a C++ compiler must be valid C++.
Not coincidentally though, most C — including its standard library (for things like printf) — is actually valid C++ as well and can be compiled with a C++ compiler. Therefore, your program is fine once you include stdio.h.
It is, of course, better to include <cstdio> if you are writing new code, which puts the library names in the std namespace; only old C code should include <stdio.h>.

Obligatory nitpicking that <cstdio> is allowed to duplicate the contents in the global namespace, just like <stdio.h> is allowed to duplicate them in std, IIRC.

Just nit-picking.  printf is not written in C++ compatible C.  It is written in C.  Only the function signature needs to be understood by C++ and the linker handles the rest.

@HolyBlackCat You mean that the names then are global as well as in std? I didn't know that, actually!

@Peter-ReinstateMonica That's what cppreference says. But in the standard I only found the part that <cstdio> can duplicate the declarations in the global scope, and didn't find the opposite, but I could've missed it.

@Jason Natural language is so inexact. ;-) What I'm saying is that "the C standard library" as perceived by the users (i.e., its API) is formally part of the C++ standard, and hence the language.

It is correct to use C compilation units (ie libraries etc) in C++ code if you compile those compilation units using the C compiler. It is a widespread programming practice.
Very often programmers write C++ wrappers around C libraries.

All true, but I don't this is what the OP was talking about.

@JohnBollinger he asks how to use C code in larger project

He asks about using C code in a C++ "script", and gives a single file example. He also asks about implications of that on a larger project.  I take that as different from linking libraries written in C into a project otherwise written in C++, but YMMV.
